# How to use SocketCAN via Unix Domain Sockets in Java?

Tags: java, can-bus, unix-socket, socketcan

I am trying to figure out how to use a [SocketCAN](https://docs.kernel.org/networking/can.html) connection in Java.

As stated in the [SocketCAN doc](https://docs.kernel.org/networking/can.html), SocketCAN is designed very similar to TCP and UDP Sockets. It also provides a network interface for each connected CAN bus. These are also listed for example by `ifconfig`:

```
can0: flags=193<UP,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 16
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

But the `can0` interface is not listed by `NetworkInterface.networkInterfaces()` in Java for example. I guess, because it's not a TCP/UDP interface with an IP. CAN is a different network, without addresses.

I would like give it a try by using the Unix Domain Socket support in Java. But I couldn't find out the file path of the CAN interface to build a `UnixDomainSocketAddress`.

I know there are tools that route the SocketCAN to a network connection, like [socketcand](https://github.com/dschanoeh/socketcand). And also I found libs that make SocketCAN usage possible via JNI or JNA.
But I would like to give it a try without extra JNI/JNA implementations and extra tools.

Comment: Have you found any more information on this? I'm going to be trying something similar soon.

Comment: No, sorry I didn't find an answer yet. But not an high priority for me. So didn't invest more time yet.

Comment: Still no luck?  I need to do the same thing and have been doing a LOT of searching...